# SwiftUI Picker selection parameter giving "Expression type 'Binding<_>' is ambiguous without more context" error

Tags: binding, swiftui, optional-chaining

I'm getting a ***Expression type 'Binding<_>' is ambiguous without more context*** error at `$order.quantity.contracts` in the following code:

```
struct ContractsPickerView: View {
    @Binding var order: Order
    
    var question: String
            
    var body: some View {
                         
                        Error
                          |
                          |
                          V                
        Picker(selection: $order.quantity.contracts, label: Text("\(question)").font(.headline)) { 
            ForEach(0..<101, id: \.self) { contracts in
                Text("\(contracts)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, Xcode is not offering me the `contracts` attribute in the `Quantity` class after typing `$order.quantity.`.  Here are the models:

```
struct Order {
    var quantity: Quantity?
}

struct Quantity: Hashable {
    private var userEnteredContracts: Int?
    var contracts: Int {
        get {
            return userEnteredContracts
        }
        set(newContracts) {
            userEnteredContracts = newContracts
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain the issue and offer a solution please?

Comment: How did you declare `order` in your view?

Comment: @pawello2222 - just updated question to show how order was declared.

Comment: This is because `quantity` can be nil. So in reality you're trying to do `$order.quantity?.contracts` which is not allowed. How should your app behave if `quality` is nil? Also your code will not compile: `contracts` are of type `Int` but you return `userEnteredContracts` which are of type `Int?`.

Comment: Thanks, @pawello2222!  I had assumed Swift would unwrap `quantity?` but obviously, I was mistaken!  And yes, thanks for the pointing out that `contracts` and `userEnteredContracts` data type must match.  I've updated the `Order` model such that `var quantity: Quantity` and `Quantity` model such that `var contracts: Int?`.  Feel free to post answer so you can get credit.  Otherwise, I'm happy to answer the question as well.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your binding to work `quantity` can't be nil.

In reality instead of:

```
$order.quantity.contracts
```

you're trying to do

```
$order.quantity?.contracts
```

which is not allowed. How should your Picker behave if `quantity` is nil?

A solution may be to make `quantity` non-optional:

```
struct Order {
    var quantity: Quantity
}
```

---

Also note that your code will not compile: `contracts` are of type `Int` but you return `userEnteredContracts` which are of type `Int?`

You may want to make `contracts` optional:

```
struct Quantity: Hashable {
    private var userEnteredContracts: Int?
    var contracts: Int? {
        get {
            return userEnteredContracts
        }
        set(newContracts) {
            userEnteredContracts = newContracts
        }
    }
}
```

or provide a default value:

```
struct Quantity: Hashable {
    private var userEnteredContracts: Int?
    var contracts: Int {
        get {
            return userEnteredContracts ?? 0
        }
        set(newContracts) {
            userEnteredContracts = newContracts
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if using the picker, I needed to modify the content in the `ForEach` loop from `Text("\(contracts)")` to `Text(String(contracts)).tag(contracts as Int?)`.